# Push a folder in a Git repo to another repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a Git repo that has subfolders like:

```
- myproject
  + folder1
  + folder2
  + folder3
```

How can I push a subfolder (i.e. folder1) to another Git repo? I thought submodule was the right approach, but I don't think I'm using it correctly or if it applies here. The way I tried using submodule was:

```
git submodule add git@urlofnewrepo folder1
```

But that results in an error as:

```
'folder1' already exists in the index
```

Comment: Is there an existing repository for folder1 or are you planning to split it off into its own repository?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, It will be split off into its own repository.

Comment: Does this help [How to tear apart a repository: the Git way](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/tear-apart-repository-git-way/)?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, sorry it took awhile, but that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R0MANARMY pointed me to http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/tear-apart-repository-git-way/ which basically accomplishes what I want to do. The workflow is:

```
git clone remote_repo_url new_repo_name
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter folder_to_filter
```

So in my case, it was:

```
git clone remote_repo_url new_repo_name
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter folder1
```

This resulted in the folder "new_repo_name" only containing files from "folder1".

Answer (score 0):

Try `--force` key, like:

```
git submodule add --force git@urlofnewrepo folder1
```

Comment: I tried the '--force' flag, but it still threw the error:'folder1' already exists in the index.